# Optimizing RC values on monostable multivibrator accounting for retrigger timing

Tags: multivibrator, monostable

I am attempting to use a retriggerable monostable multivibrator [datasheet](https://componentsearchengine.com/Datasheets/1/74LV123D,118.pdf) to tell me if an engine is on or off.  The input to the IC is a square wave usually between 100-200Hz 0-3.3V.  The signal is coming off of the engine's ignition coil, but is being taken to 0-3.3V using an optocoupler circuit.  The multivibrator will be continuously retriggered producing a steady 3.3V logic high signal when the engine is on.

The part where I am confused about is what should tw (pulse width) be such that the IC is always retriggering? According to the datasheet tw can be found using:  tw = K*R*C where R is in KOhms and C is in pF, and tw is in ns.  K is approximately 0.45.  Assume I select 200kOhms and 1uF my tw will be 90ms.  Because my signal is 200Hz I should see a peak every 5ms.  Therefore for every multivibrator I have 90/5 or 18 chances to retrigger the IC.

If I wanted to increase the number of retrigger possibilities per multivibrator pulse I could just keep increasing the capacitance for example.  However there appears to be a "minimum retrigger time" which grows as the tw increases.  Computing this for the 200kOhm 1uF case yields @Vcc 3V: 1.5s.  Am I calculating this wrong? **If this were true than I could not produce a continuous logic high output under these conditions.**

What RC values would be best to assure retriggering and at the same time having some noise immunity such that if the input pulse stopped for a few ms the output wouldn't indicate the engine was off?

[image: retrigger equations]

Comment: I'd like to know a lot more about the *signal coming off of the engine's ignition coil*. But given that you have an opto involved, I think it can be arranged to work with [this circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/262854/38098), which is retriggerable and for which the computation of values is quite easy. (The collector/drain of the opto can be arranged to replace the indicated switch.)

Comment: I took a look at this, it seems rather complex.  I would prefer to use an IC if possible due to the footprint and ease of understanding.  Also I think with proper selection of resistors and capacitors the IC I selected should work

Comment: It's a nice dual and I've buckets of them from decades back (not that particular version, though.) I've used them for similar purposes. I was just tossing out a more boutique (less sensitive to IC availability issues -- plus it is very low-power) approach that also works well. You have every right to use what is more comfortable for you. I only wanted to see if you were open to another idea. It's enough that you aren't. If I get a moment, I'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the calculation correctly, but I think the equation is wrong.

If you change the * symbol to a +, it gives a result that makes more sense.

With the 200 kΩ resistor and 1 μF capacitor, you get 9.5 ms with the 5 V equation. Changing that one operator in the 3 V equation makes the calculation 7.5 ms as shown in MATLAB.

[image]

There's no way to know for sure what the correct equation is unless there's enough info in the datasheet to derive it, but if you have a signal generator and a scope, you could test how it functions with different input frequencies.

If that is the correct equation, you could change the resistance to 265 kΩ or greater to get a retrigger time of 10 ms (100 Hz)

500 kΩ would be a better option to ensure the system will always retrigger by stretching the retrigger time to around 20 ms. Here are the calculations for such:

rt1_fix = retrigger time in seconds for 3.0 V (possibly fixed)

rt2 = retrigger time in seconds for 5.0 V

[image]

Here is the equation for solving for an R value based on time in seconds.
For 20 ms => t = 0.020:

$$\frac{2\cdot 10^{10}\cdot t-820}{3\cdot C^{0.9}+20}$$

You can also replace C with any value you want.

Comment: You may be correct about the equation issues, I hope this is the case.  I requested some tech support from nexperia, and I can confirm this.  Usually they reply within 24hrs or so.

Comment: I see why you are questioning the 3V equation, because the 5V equation has a + not a *.  Based on the current documentation the 3V and 5V supply would give radically different retrigger times.